# Editing a list to add strings in in different positions to output a formatted string

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a column of numbers:

```
195,191
22,23
18,252
172,221
```

I want to efficiently **add** the **following characters** onto it and **turn** it into a **string** to output this in idle:

```
goto(195+position,(191 * xy) - y)
goto(22+position,(23 * xy) - y)
goto(18+position,(252 * xy) - y)
goto(172+position,(221 * xy) - y)
```

The characters: `goto(, +position, (, * xy), -y)` have to be in the position shown above.

I have tried using Python's `[:]` to slice  on array, but it doesn't work because the data digits change between 2 and 3 digit numbers in data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) together with [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) like this:

```
lines = ["195,191", "22,23", "18,252", "172,221"]
for s in lines:
    print("goto({0[0]}+position,({0[1]} * xy) - y)".format(s.split(",")))
```

this will print

```
goto(195+position,(191 * xy) - y)
goto(22+position,(23 * xy) - y)
goto(18+position,(252 * xy) - y)
goto(172+position,(221 * xy) - y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split and then concatenate string like :

```
lines = ["195,191", "22,23", "18,252", "172,221"]
for i in lines:
    print "goto("+ i.split(',')[0] +"position,("+i.split(',')[1] +" * xy) - y) "
```

Output :

```
goto(195+position,(191 * xy) - y) 
goto(22+position,(23 * xy) - y) 
goto(18+position,(252 * xy) - y) 
goto(172+position,(221 * xy) - y)
```

Found it as easy way